# Ubuntu collects CSI use two NICs

Tags: linux

I have one laptop with two wifi adapters. I want to collect [csi data](https://github.com/dhalperi/linux-80211n-csitool-supplementary) simultaneously using two NICs(intel 5300).
The connection looks like the paper Phaser did. Does anybody know how to run command binding two NICs in monitor mode?

Comment: Please advise make and model of your laptop. Please collect model number from the serial number sticker; other 'models' are marketing names, and not technically useful. Please also advise how you added the second WiFi adapter, as nearly all laptops only have one PCIe connector for WiFi adapters. Please click [edit] and put that information in your question; please don't use Add Comment, but instead use [edit]. Also, who is Phaser and what's the URL for their paper?